# Uniqueness and invariance of the LDLT decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, na.numerical-analysis, matrix-analysis, matrix-theory

A real symmetric positive semi-definite matrix $A$ can be decomposed in the form

$A = P^TLDL^TP$,

where $P$ is a permutation matrix, $L$ is a lower unit triangular matrix and $D$ is a diagonal matrix.

**Questions**

**(a)** Is this decomposition unique?

**(b)** Let $B = \Pi^TA\Pi$, where $\Pi$ is a permutation matrix. It follows that

$B = \Pi^TP^TLDL^TP\Pi = Q^TLDL^TQ$,

where $Q = \Pi P$ is a permutation matrix, too. If the LDLT decomposition is unique, this means that it is invariant to simultaneous permutations of rows and columns of a matrix, right?

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not unique. For instance, for $A=I$, $L=D=I$, and any $P$ work. Or $A=0$, and then $D=0$ and any $L,P$ work.

The version without the permutation matrix is unique for positive definite matrices, because it is essentially a diagonally scaled LU, and it is a classical result that LU is unique for matrices with nonsingular leading principal submatrices, and this class includes positive definite matrices.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, what is important to me is uniqueness up to a permutation. This is the purpose of question (b). $A = 0$ is kind of pathological example. Is $LDL^T$, or $L$ or $D$ unique for positive semi-definite matrices (except for $A = 0$)?

I mean, $P$ is obviously not unique because of (b), so the question is what about the other matrices?

Comment: @user3749105 There are non-zero counterexamples as well. For instance, take $\begin{bmatrix}0  &0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @Poloni: $D$ seems unique, or not?

Comment: @user3749105 No -- just take a random positive definite matrix, and different choices for $P$ will give different factors $D$. I don't really think there is any meaningful uniqueness result, apart from the one I have stated in my answer ($LDL^\top$ without permutation, positive definite $A$).